# Can you recover a distribution from mollification?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ be a Schwartz distribution. Given $\rho \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ define the convolution as the function  $$x\mapsto (f\ast\rho)(x):=\langle f, \rho (\cdot -x)\rangle.$$

I believe this function should be smooth. Anyway my question is: suppose further that $\rho\geq 0$ and $\int \rho = 1$ and for $\varepsilon>0$, define 
$$\rho_\varepsilon(x):=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rho(x\varepsilon^{-1}).$$
Then is it the case that $f\ast\rho_\varepsilon\to f$ in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$?

Comment: yes of course. since the convolution is commutative  and associative, $f  \ast \rho_\epsilon \ast \varphi = f  \ast (\rho_\epsilon \ast \varphi) \to f \ast \varphi$ for every Schwartz function $\varphi$ (the argument being that $(\rho_\epsilon \ast \varphi \to \varphi$ in the Schwartz functions topology, i.e. with $\phi_n = \varphi - \rho_{1/n} \ast \varphi$, we have  $\max_x |\phi_n^{(k)}(x)| \to 0$ for every $k$. by the definition of a Schwartz distribution, $\phi \mapsto f \ast \phi(x)$ is continuous in $\phi$ for this topology)

Comment: you should also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Convolution "convolution of a distribution with a distribution of compact support". here $\rho_\epsilon$ is a test function, hence also a distribution of compact support, and $\rho_\epsilon \to \delta$ in $S'(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, yes. For a proof, first require a few prerequisites. From F. G. Friedlander and M. Joshi's *Introduction to the Theory of Distributions*, we have

> **Theorem 1.2.1.** Let $f \in C_c^k(\mathbb R)$, let $\rho \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be such that $\rho \geq 0$ and $\int \rho = 1$, let
>   $\rho_\varepsilon = \varepsilon^{-1} \rho( x / \varepsilon)$, and let $f_\varepsilon = f * \rho_\varepsilon$. Then $\partial^\alpha f_\varepsilon \to \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly as $\varepsilon \to 0$ for all $|\alpha| \leq k$.

We borrow the notation
$$
f_\varepsilon = f * \rho_\varepsilon
$$
for your tempered distribution $f$. We also define $\mathcal D(\mathbb R) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ to be a set of "test functions" with dual space "the distributions" $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. The relation to the Schwartz functions $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ and the tempered distributions $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ is
$$
\mathcal D \subset \mathcal S \subset \mathcal S' \subset \mathcal D';
$$
it's true that

> **Theorem.** $\mathcal D$ is dense in $\mathcal D'$.

from which it follows that all inclusions are dense.

---

We make two key observations from the above two theorems before finally attacking the proof.

- $f \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R) \subset \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$, and since $\mathcal D(\mathbb R) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$, there exists a sequence of $\psi_n \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R)$ such that 
  $$
  \text{$\psi_n \to f \qquad$ in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ as $n\to\infty$.} \tag{1}
  $$
  It follows that 
  $$
  \text{for each $\varepsilon > 0, \qquad \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon \to f_\varepsilon\qquad$ in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ as $n\to\infty$.} \tag{2}
  $$
- By Theorem 1.2.1, for each fixed $n$, we have $\partial^\beta (\psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon) \to \partial^\beta \psi_n$ uniformly as $\varepsilon \to 0$ for all multi-indices $\beta$. Since $\psi_n$ and $\rho_\varepsilon$ are compactly supported, it follows that for each $n$, $\| \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon - \psi_n \|_{\alpha, \beta} \to 0$ for all multi-indices $\alpha, \beta$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. The same conclusion follows when considered as tempered distributions:
  $$
  \text{for each $n$, $\qquad \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon \to \psi_n\qquad$ in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.} \tag{3}
  $$

Finally, 
$f_\varepsilon \to f$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb R)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ iff for all $\varphi \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$, we have $\langle f_\varepsilon, \varphi \rangle \to \langle f, \varphi \rangle$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. To prove this is the case, let $\varepsilon' > 0$. Then

\begin{align*}
f - f_\varepsilon &= f - \psi_n + \psi_n - f_\varepsilon \\
&= (f - \psi_n) + (\psi_n - \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon) + (\psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon - f_\varepsilon) \\
\implies \left| \left\langle f - f_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right| & \leq \left| \left\langle f - \psi_n, \varphi \right\rangle \right| + \left| \left\langle \psi_n - \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right| + \left| \left\langle \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon - f_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right|
\end{align*}
Regardless of $\varepsilon$, we may bound the first and third terms of the latter expression by $\varepsilon'$ if we choose $n$ sufficiently large according to $(1)$ and $(2)$. This gives us
$$
\left| \left\langle f - f_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right| \leq 2 \varepsilon' + \left| \left\langle \psi_n - \psi_n * \rho_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right|,
$$
and then applying $(3)$, we have
$$
\left| \left\langle f - f_\varepsilon, \varphi \right\rangle \right| \leq 3 \varepsilon'
$$
for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, which proves the claim.